# NSDocumentController closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate does not call canCloseDocumentWithDelegate of my NSPersistentDocument subclass

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nspersistentdocument

According to Apple's docs, `closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate` (from `NSDocumentController`) should call `canCloseDocumentWithDelegate` of `NSDocument` for all open documents if you quit an application.

In my `NSPersistentDocument`-based app I need to override `canCloseDocumentWithDelegate` in order to warn the user in case a certain server functionality is still running when the document closes. This has nothing to do with any data changes. 
This works when the user closes a single document; I can present a sheet with the warning and let the user cancel the closing process.

However, my version of `canCloseDocumentWithDelegate` does not get called when the app is quit. What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple Developer Technical Support this is a known issue. I finally cut the automatic wiring of the app's quit menu item and handle it all by myself. I needed to make the server functionality information of the document available from the outside (in this example the state of `optionButton`) and added this function to the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (IBAction)terminateGracefully:(id)sender {
    BOOL optionOn = FALSE;
    for (Document *doc in NSApp.orderedDocuments) {
        if (doc.optionButton.state == NSControlStateValueOn) {
            optionOn = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if (optionOn) {
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setMessageText:@"Checkbox in some window is on"];
        [alert setInformativeText:@"Something is going on. If you close the app now, it will stop. Close anyway?\n"];
        [alert setAlertStyle:NSAlertStyleCritical];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Don't close"];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Close anyway"];

        NSModalResponse resp = [alert runModal];

        if (resp == NSAlertSecondButtonReturn) {
            // We really want to close
            [NSApp terminate:sender];
        }

    } else {
        [NSApp terminate:sender];
    }
}
```

Then I bound the app's quit menu item to `terminateGracefully:`

[image: Xcode binding]